# Submiting form on keyhit. Butut not on every keyhit

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-plugins, onkeyup

i'm currently using this to get the results without enter clicking or Submiting form, just by typing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#Form_id").bind('keyup',function() {
                    var value = $('#Input_id').val();
                    $.post('process_search.php?term='+value+'&buscar=1',{value:value}, function(data){
                        $("#router").html(data);
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Ok, this works great. but has big small little problem: if i type 'hello' sends 4 requests.

In order to solve that, i thought that i could try to detect when a **blank space** has ben typed and then submit the form. Solution A

Another solution would be to detect when last keyhit was in x miliseconds, solution 2

I like both, but i would apritiate opinions on both, and some help of corse :$

Thanks!

Comment: Much better to do it during a quiet period (i.e., no keystrokes for last 3 seconds or something along those lines), but the whole approach seems pretty network-antagonistic, unless you're facilitating real-time collaboration (like Google Docs) or progressive search (like Google) or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be use setTimeout and clearTimeout so you can delay after x milliseconds have elapsed.

```
$(function () {
    var delay;
    $("#Form_id").bind('keyup', function () {
        var value = $('#Input_id').val();
        clearTimeout(delay)
        delay = setTimeout(function () {
            $.post('process_search.php?term=' + value + '&buscar=1', {
                value: value
            }, function (data) {
                $("#router").html(data);
            });
        }, 1000);

        return false;
    });
});
```

**Simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/EG2Md/).**

Comment: Thank you my friend! i will try and let you know :), that's for 1s delay, right?

Comment: That it's just what i needed !

Answer (score 1):

Ext Core http://docs.sencha.com/core/ lets you do it easily like the following. Check out the documentation for Ext.Element

```
function sendRequest(e) {...}
Ext.get("#Form_id").on('keyup', sendRequest, null, {buffer: 1000});
```

I know the post was about jQuery, my point is that this functionality can be abstracted and I can't believe jQuery doesn't offer that option.